# SOAP Error when trying to use the Cybersource module within Magento

Tags: php, soap, magento

I have tried to find a more specific answer and could not find anything helpful in regards to this error.  It may simply be that I am unfamiliar with Magento or the cybersource module or both but either way, I just cannot understand what this message is trying to tell me.

This is an exception that not only shows up while debugging but also if I capture all SMTP traffic going out on my dev machine, it shows up in the email that you would get upon failure.

```
Exception: Strict Notice: Declaration of Mage_Cybersource_Model_Api_ExtendedSoapClient::__doRequest() 
should be compatible with that of SoapClient::__doRequest()  in
C:\code\app\code\local\Mage\Cybersource\Model\Api\ExtendedSoapClient.php on line 75 
in C:\code\app\code\core\Mage\Core\functions.php on line 245
```

what I am doing when this occurs is trying to submit an order.  I have added items to the shopping cart, logged in, put in shipping data and reviewed the order and when I hit Submit Order, it chunks for a while and gives me this message.  When I debug through the code (which takes FOREVER) I finally get to the point where the cybersource module is trying to authorize through the SOAP system and then it throws this error.

the exact placement it errors is around this method

```
protected function getSoapApi($options = array())
{
    $wsdl = $this->getConfigData('test') ? self::WSDL_URL_TEST  : self::WSDL_URL_LIVE;
    return new Mage_Cybersource_Model_Api_ExtendedSoapClient($wsdl, $options);
}
```

any ideas would be very helpful on what to look for or even what this message means.  Also, I have SOAP installed and enabled in PHP 5.3.6 running in a windows environment with apache 2.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a PHP error about subclassing SoapClient. Basically, it happens when you have something like this:

```
class Foo {
    public function doSomething() {
      // ...
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public function doSomething($totallyUnreasonableParameter) {
      // ...
    }
}
```

Your issue is almost certainly an issue with the version of SOAP installed on your server. I haven't seen this in particular, but it could have to do with the PHP version (5.3.6) which I am not aware of as a supported version.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to Joe, I did some digging and found that Cybersource wrote its module to work with PHP5.2.1 and in that version the SOAP client was different than on PHP 5.3.  the __doRequest method had an item added to it that was causing the inconsistency.  so I changed the code in the ExtendedSoapClient.php file from
From

```
public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version)
```

to

```
public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $oneWay = 0)
```

and that seemed to fix this error.  Thanks Joe for your help into this error.